# Magento 2: How to hide the price for guest user only wholesale group user can see price

Tags: magento2, price, customer-group

How to hide the price for guest user only wholesale group user can see price in
is there any script or code or some free extension please suggest ?

Answer (score 2):

[Product Available Extension](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ProductAvailable) allows the store owner to hide the product price and add to cart button from guests or certain customer groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the price by override the wrapResult function in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;
use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;


class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{ 
    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {
     $result = '';
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();           
     $httpContext=$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
     $isLoggedIn=$httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

     if($isLoggedIn){
       $result = '<div class="price-box ' . $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
        'data-role="priceBox" ' .
        'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
        '>' . $html . '</div>';
     }
    return $result; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Vinz , i have tried your code it is not working

Comment: On which page do you need to hide the price ?

Comment: i want to hide product list page, product details page and everywhere for guest user only login user with wholesale group can see price

Comment: @Vinz Does this solution also work with FPC? Won't it save the $isLoggedIn state of the first user that saves the FPC?

Comment: Hi,@Vinz,I tried above script but still no effect on price.can you provide some other method?

Comment: Hi @AnikeshShahi, what is your magento version ?

Comment: @Vinz,magento v-2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Adding my opinion to @Vinz answer, you should get logged-in customer group id

```
<?php $context = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context'); ?>
<?php $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH); ?>
<?php $customerGroupId = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_GROUP); ?>

<?php if($isLoggedIn && $customerGroupID == 'WHOLESALE ENTITY ID') // you should put the entity id to WHOLESALE ENTITY ID

   <?php $result = '<div class="price-box ' . $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
    'data-role="priceBox" ' .
    'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
    '>' . $html . '</div>';
 ?>
return $result;
```

Comment: It is not working