# How to control price visibility of product from Magento 2 admin panel?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, visibility

I want to control the ***price visibility of products*** from admin panel. actually, I create an attribute price-control as a display on the following image. if price control set to yes, the price of the product should not display, and instead of it a custom text ***on demand*** should display. I will be very thankful to you, if you give me some code related help

[image]

Comment: You can look for few free extension available which server the same purpose. Primarily you want to ask the customer to call for further queries for specific products.

Comment: Can you refer some of them ?

Comment: It is not correct as per the norms of stack exchange to refer specific extensions. But I am sure, you will be able to find one if you search around a bit.

Comment: ok. i try to find myself

Comment: You can edit your question later with the comments that you were not able to find any free extension, in case you fail to do so so that anyone from the StackExchange community can give you code related help.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209091/magento-2-how-to-hide-the-price-for-guest-user-only-wholesale-group-user-can-se?rq=1

I think this link can be a help for you!