# Magento 2.2.6 how to develope loggedin customer only show price in website

Tags: magento2, price, product-view, listing

I am using Magento 2.2.6 I need to customize and if any plugin available for logged-in customer show only price not show for guest user in Magento website. if anyone idea reply me. I have try to one module integrate but not hide price in listing and detail.

Comment: Please review this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209091/magento-2-how-to-hide-the-price-for-guest-user-only-wholesale-group-user-can-se
I hope it helps you.

Comment: @Raj I tried it but not working it

Answer (score 0):

You need to override price renderer.

First, create a sample module. We consider here "Stackoverflow_Answer"

Create etc/di.xml and put below code

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Stackoverflow\Answer\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Stackoverflow\Answer\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
```

Now created FinalPriceBox.php under Pricing/Render folder and put below code.

```
<?php
namespace Stackoverflow\Answer\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;
use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface $saleableItem,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $price,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool $rendererPool,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Pricing\Renderer\SalableResolverInterface $salableResolver = null,
        \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface $minimalPriceCalculator = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, 
                            $saleableItem, 
                            $price, 
                            $rendererPool, 
                            $data, 
                            $salableResolver, 
                            $minimalPriceCalculator);
    }

    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $httpContext = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
        $isLoggedIn = $httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        if($isLoggedIn){
            return '<div class="price-box ' . $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                '>' . $html . '</div>';
        }else{
            $wording = 'Please Login To See Price';
            return '<div class="" ' .
                'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                '>'.$wording.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

I had the same task yesterday, it works. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Not working i m tried same code but not reflect on listing page and detail page

Comment: It should be. please check this class "Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" and check wrapResult is called or not. It may be conflict with another module too.